# New rails 4.1 mailer preview action not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Rails has 607 open issues...so, rather than plugging that hole even more I though Id try here first.  I have upgraded to 4.1 and am implementing rails mailer previews.  I tried upgrading my existing mailer and adding tests/mailers/previews directory.  When that gave the following error I tried generating a new mailer.  Same error.

```
 class NotifierPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
    def welcome
      Notifier.welcome(User.first)
    end
  end
```

results in this error:

```
 The action 'notifier' could not be found for Rails::MailersController
```

I've tried searching google, the docs, stack overflow, but nothing eludes to this error.

Anyone experience this or have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are using `UserMailer` with `NotifierPreview`. Change **NotifierPreview** to **UserMailerPreview** and it will start working.  Check the example implementation https://github.com/RichIsOnRails/ActionMailerPreviewsExample and tutorial.

Cheers!!

Comment: I wish it were that simple...but, my naming is correct.

Comment: Did you check the example git repo? it uses Rails 4.1.

Comment: Turns out the prob (so it seems) is in my routes file.  I have two routes "get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))', get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'" that are evidently deprecated...or will be soon.  This is via a comment in the rails issue I submitted.  When I remove these routes I get other errors...at least now I know the root cause.  I'm using the link you shared to help get things fixed up.  Thanks, Maximus!

Answer (score 82):

The default preview path is `/test/mailers/previews` but rspec will override this to be `/spec/mailers/previews`

You can set the path to be whatever you like with:

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/test/mailers/previews"
```

Comment: My hero! Mailer previews suddenly stopped working- just got a blank/white page instead of the index. Didn't realize rspec screwed with my mailer paths.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using rspec, make sure that the `rspec-rails` gem is being loaded in the development environment, otherwise Rails will look for the previews under the /test folder, not /spec.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the line(s)

```
get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

from your `routes.rb`

As @hellion says in a comment on the previous answer this is the solution to this problem.

Comment: I was unable to remove the catch all routes from my app, so this was helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130130/what-are-the-routes-i-need-to-set-up-to-preview-emails-using-rails-4-1-actionmai